# Hierarchical Select Question

Tags: routes

I don't know if its possible at all but I need something like what is seen in [this demo](http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select/menu) for one of the menus with [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module. This works fine when I use it for a vocabulary with hierarchical terms but don't know how to use it for generic Drupal menus.

Comment: Are you using Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: I use drupal vesion 6

Answer (score 1):

You have a separate submodule for using Hierarchical Select with menus, the same as for taxonomy terms.

So, for taxonomy terms you have **Hierarchical Select Content Taxonomy** submodule (hs_taxonomy), and for menus you have **Hierarchical Select Menu** (hs_menu) submodule, which you should use in your case.

Click on 'Show config' links on the demo page you have mentioned to see the details.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create drop down menu but still couldn't figure out how to add only/just Primary menu/links to the drop down I did something like this but it displays all the menus in the system

```
$form['select_some_term'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hierarchical_select',
    '#title' => t('Please Select'),
    '#size' => 1,
    '#config' => array(
      'module' => 'hs_menu',
      'params' => array(
        'exclude' => '',
      ),
      'save_lineage'    => 0,
      'enforce_deepest' => 0,
      'entity_count'    => 0,
      'resizable'       => 1,
      'level_labels' => array(
        'status' => 0,
      ),
      'dropbox' => array(
        'status'   => 0,
      ),
      'editability' => array(
        'status'           => 0,
        'item_types'       => array(),
      ),
      'animation_delay'    => 400,
      'exclusive_lineages' => array(),
      'render_flat_select' => 0,
    ),
  );

  return $form;
```

I've spent hours but couldn't figure this out. Please help!